# How to query all with same id from array mongodb

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

I want to query all documents with "type" : "something" and its references with name "sId" contains the same "id".

```
{
       "system" : "test1",
       "name" : "sId",
       "id" : [ 
            "7777777"
       ]
}
```

But it is in an array, I'm not sure how to do it in Robo 3T.
Below is a sample document.

```
"_id" : 23423423,
"type" : "something",
"reference" : {
        "references" : [ 
            {
                "system" : "test1",
                "name" : "testId",
                "id" : [ 
                    "AS323232323"
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "system" : "test1",
                "name" : "sId",
                "id" : [ 
                    "7777777"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: I dont understand ""name "sId" contains the same "id". Can you elaborate more ?

Comment: basically I want all document with type:"something" with the same reference.references.id with "system":"test1"